# Combo Box using CSS

Tags: css

i have a combobox on my page. I want to have it on the right side of the page. how can i use styles to bring it to the right of the page and also customize a bit?

```
<span class="_Title_bar_option">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        Option</span>
</div>

._Title_bar_option
{
    background-color: Green;
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    display:inline;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: please post some code.
I think that you need a position:absolute; and a right:0;

Comment: i have done some experiments but was failed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
right: 0;
```

to your rules, you've already declared `position: fixed;` so it will work.

[**See Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e58Bu/)

Comment: what if i want to customize my combobox? :/

Comment: I don't see a combobox anywhere here. A combo box is a `<select>` element, I don't see anything like that around here. As for customizing your span, what exactly are you trying to customize? What are you trying to achieve?